# Install stack project extra-deps with stack

Tags: haskell-stack

How can I build project `a` with dependency `b` when both are not found in `stack` indices?

I used `stack install` on `b`, added `extra-deps` but still failed to build `a`.

```
Didn't see b in your package indices. Updating and trying again.
```

Why `b` is not in my "package indices"? How should I build project `a`?

Comment: could you show us your stack.yaml file?

Comment: and the cabal file for your project ?